# background drag&drop with moving content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

there I'm looking for help to make a darg&drop map with content en it. I'm using draggable-UI already but the style I can't-do what I want. I already made a test. but the content is not fixed onto the background (div called in append()). I'd link to do something like grepolis draggable background. Here is what I've already done :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test de Map</title>
    <style>
        .globalMap {width:500px;height:400px;margin:50px auto; border:#291f12 2px solid;overflow:hidden;position:relative}
        .map {width:2048px; height:1440px; position:absolute;top:0; left:0}
        .overlay {background:url(https://terre-noire.fr/static/img/carte3.jpg) no-repeat top left;width:2048px; height:1440px; position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
        .overlay p {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script async>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.map').append('<div class="overlay"><p>test de drag</p></div>');
        });

        var imageOffset = {
            top:0,
            left:0,
        };

        $(function() {
            $(".overlay").draggable({
                drag: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".overlay").css('background-position', (ui.position.left + imageOffset.left) + 'px ' + (ui.position.top + imageOffset.top) + 'px');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
</body>
    <div class="globalMap">
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks already for your help. I've found so many answers already here that I'm sure you'll help me well :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer the Jquery draggable UI script to your codes.

Hope this helps :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test de Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
    <style>
        .globalMap {width:500px;height:400px;margin:50px auto; border:#291f12 2px solid;overflow:hidden;position:relative}
        .map {width:2048px; height:1440px; position:absolute;top:0; left:0}
        .overlay {background:url(https://terre-noire.fr/static/img/carte3.jpg) no-repeat top left;width:2048px; height:1440px; position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
        .overlay p {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;}
    </style>
   
    <script async>
        jQuery(function($){
            $('.map').append('<div class="overlay"><p>test de drag</p></div>');
        });

        var imageOffset = {
            top:0,
            left:0,
        };

        $(function() {
            $(".overlay").draggable({
                drag: function(event, ui) {
                    $(".overlay").css('background-position', (ui.position.left + imageOffset.left) + 'px ' + (ui.position.top + imageOffset.top) + 'px');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
</body>
    <div class="globalMap">
        <div class="map"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a discrepancy between the map and the <p> content. moreover I would like the p to remain in absolute position. and the image must not leave the frame despite an offset already placed in the code